# Optimize animations on website created with jquery for tablet

Tags: jquery, performance, mobile-website

I have a SPA website that uses extensively jQuery. All fine - looks and behaves great on all browsers.

Now I have the request to make it **tablet** friendly.

Just by opening the website on a tablet the biggest issue right seems to be that all interaction - select, loading icons ,fadeIn, fadeOut are sluggish and not smooth (as they are on the pc browsers).

What could I do? I cannot afford to rewrite the website using another framework, but if I can take advantage of features offered by frameworks like jquery mobile and such I am open to suggestions.

Links to resources are appreciated.

Comment: Main problem with tablet/mobile is that jquery animation are slow. You should use CSS3 transition when ever possible. Some jquery plugin can help you for that in some situation, but not all, see example here: https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transition.js/   Unfortunately, this plugin is no more maintained but you could find others.

Answer (score 4):

In short, use CSS transitions where ever possible. Where it isn't, ensure your animations use requestAnimationFrame.

I wrote http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/jquery-vs-css3-transitions/ a year or so back which has a contrived demo to show the difference.

https://github.com/benbarnett/jQuery-Animate-Enhanced might be able to be simply dropped in to improve performance, though it might break your site on complex animations.